# no suitable method found for add()

Tags: java, java-me

I am new to java
    "I get this error **"no suitable method found for add()"** when ever I try to run my program. Please help. What am I doing wrong? Please note that I am trying to learn how to use interface.

Here's exxample:

```
public interface Calculate {

    int add(int a, int b);
}

public abstract class Maths extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, Calculate {

    private Display display;
    Form mainForm = new Form("Calculator");
    Form testForm = new Form("Results");
    TextField at = new TextField("A=", "", 10, TextField.NUMERIC);
    TextField bt = new TextField("B=", "", 10, TextField.NUMERIC);
    StringItem resultItem = new StringItem("Result =", "");
    Command addCommand = new Command("add", Command.SCREEN, 1);

    public Maths() {
        display = Display.getDisplay(this);
        mainForm.append(at);
        mainForm.append(bt);
        mainForm.addCommand(addCommand);
        testForm.append(resultItem);
        testForm.setCommandListener(this);
        mainForm.setCommandListener(this);
    }

    public void startApp() {
        Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(mainForm);
    }

    protected final void addOrderComponent(Component c) {
    }
```

Comment: Why are you making `Maths` an `abstract` class? What subclasses of `Maths` are you going to make, and why?

Comment: You have to return `result`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I am using interface, I cannot use class to implement abstract methods can I?

Comment: @tintinmj I have tried return result, didnt work

Comment: Of course a concrete class can derive from an interface. People do it all the time. Abstract classes exist for convenience, to hold stuff that will be common to multiple implementations of the interface. You are way over-engineering this. And you definitely cannot run the program as is, because you do not have anything that can actually be instantiated.

Comment: I'm not convinced that you understand what any of these things are for, really. In the first place, why are you even creating an interface?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to to is call `add()` without passing any parameters. Hence, the error. If you don't want to pass parameters, then don't write `int a, int b` in the definition of `add()`.

What you need to do is :

```
public void add()
{
    int a, b, result;
    a = Integer.parseInt(at.getString());
    b = Integer.parseInt(bt.getString());
    result = a + b;
    //do what ever you need to do with the result.
}
```